# Is it possible to make an animation icon on the notifications window (Android)

Tags: java, android, statusbar, android-notifications

I have done some research and found that it's possible to have a progress bar in the expanded statusbar area but I am still not sure about whether the animation icon is possible or not. 
I have tried the answer of this question: [Animation in Notification bar Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view). However, the icon is not animated.
If it's not possible, could you point me to any documentation that confirms that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do this right off, but an example of an application that does this is Podkicker.  When you're downloading a file for offline listening, it is animated.

Do these help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216616/animation-in-status-bar-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view

Comment: I am checking Podkicker. Anyway, the SO question you referred is different from what I want. That question is actually about animation on ImageView.

Comment: @Jim I checked out Podkicker. It's not same as what I want. My requirement is an animation icon in the expanded statusbar area (which displays when a user pull down the notification bar). Thanks, anyway.

Comment: That's interesting because I linked two questions one titled "Animation in status bar in Android" and the other "Animation in Notification bar Cutsom View".  Maybe it's time I tried to do it myself :-)

Comment: And the video linked in the "Animation in Notification bar Cutsom View" shows what I think you are talking about.

Comment: I've tried the second answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view but it's not animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video in your referenced question (which I admit I didn't see was the same as one of the links I gave) clearly shows an animated icon there.  At about 0:35.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNcs-sS2nFU&t=0m32s (this link jumps to that part).  The arrow has a little black line move down through it repeatedly.  Seems like animation to me.  Is that what you want?

Regardless, what Android version is that on?  Maybe it's something custom from T-Mobile, I don't know, it's just some video on YouTube.

You can create a custom view for the notification, for example: http://www.roman10.net/android-custom-notification-with-progress-bar/  You might be able to use a similar idea with an [animation drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view) (same SO question again) where Roman10's got the default android image.

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.noti);
contentView.setImageViewResource(... your animated resource ...);
```

**Edit**

So in the end RemoteViews doesn't support animation in the image resource as far as I can tell.  But I figured out a way to work around that and it is possibly expensive, but I haven't profiled it to see how the CPU usage is.

I started with the code at roman10 (link above) and made a couple of modifications.

yinyangAnim.xml + animation frame .png files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yinyang0" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yinyang1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yinyang2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yinyang3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yinyang4" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yinyang5" android:duration="150" />    
</animation-list>
```

Add another thread creation to the start button click:

```
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        int frameIndex = 0;
                        mRun = true;
                        while (mRun) {
                            ++frameIndex;
                            SystemClock.sleep(100);
                            BitmapDrawable frame = (BitmapDrawable) yinyangAnimation.getFrame(frameIndex);
                            noti.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.status_icon, frame.getBitmap());
                            nm.notify(STATUS_BAR_NOTIFICATION, noti);
                            if (frameIndex >= yinyangAnimation.getNumberOfFrames()-1) {
                                frameIndex = 0;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                  }).start();
```

Add to ProgressBarNotificationActivity.onCreate()

```
     ImageView yinyang = new ImageView(this);
     yinyang.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yinyang_anim);
     yinyangAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) yinyang.getBackground();
```

And the private variable of course: `private AnimationDrawable yinyangAnimation;`

Pressing the start button in the app and viewing the notification shows the spinning yin-yang for me.  I got the yin-yang at loadinfo.net and split it using ImageMagick command line (ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The icon on the video is really animated. However, I followed your answer but still can't get it working. I forked the project you referred and added the animation part as you suggested. My code is at https://github.com/pt2121/roman10-android-tutorial/tree/master/ProgressBarNotification My animation code works fine on ImageView but not on the RemoteViews (StatusBar). Not sure what I missed.

Comment: I've also tried this answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-cutsom-view. I cannot get it working. If the code works for you, is it possible to share your example project? Appreciated.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Although I think it's expensive because notification is repeatedly sent, I accepted your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Answering these always teaches me something too.